# how to easily read Python built-in types from a file

Tags: python

I have a file which lists values of some Python built-in types:  None, integers, and strings, with proper Python syntax, including escaping.  For example, the file might look like this:

```
2 
"""\\nfoo
bar
""" 'foo bar'
None
```

I then want to read that file into the array of the values.  For the above example, the array would be:

```
[2, '\\nfoo\nbar\n', 'foo bar', None]
```

I can do this by carefully parsing and/or using `split` function.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: What are the rules for how values are separated in this file? The simplest rule I can think of would be "any whitespace that's not inside quotes", but that probably isn't all that easy to implement.

Comment: yes correct, any whitespace that is not quoted, is the separator

Comment: that's my problem, it does not seem easy, that's my question, is there a painless way, I guess the answers seems "no"

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? What's the end goal? If you don't have a precise definition of how the individual elements are separated, as Marius points out, then you are basically asking for a parser that reads your mind... and may read it wrong :-P

Comment: I am telling you, separated by white spaces.  I am doing this, so that the users of my script, can edit a "configuration file", in which there are Python values, and the script would read them.

Comment: You are using the wrong approach.  If you want a configuration file that contains native Python values, include the *assignment* as well in the configuration file, eg: `max_iterations = 2`, `doc_title = """\nfoo\nbar"""`, `sub_title = 'foo bar'`, `default_index = None`.  Then simply import the file to access the defined values.

Comment: Forget that these are “valid” Python literals, and write your own parser instead.

Comment: @LarryLustig yes Larry I know, but, the users would have to know the names of variables.  They don't want to have to know that.  Only the values.

Comment: If you supply the configuration file, they would only have to replace the values.  It is enormously more error prone to rely on their following the *order* of values and, indeed, having to remember the types.  A standard configuration file with comments is much, much less likely to cause problems (I would wager money that you find this out on your own).

Comment: @LarryLustig that's an excellent point Larry, I must think it through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend changing your file format. That said, what you have is parseable. It might get harder to parse if you have multi-token values like lists, but with only None, ints, and strings, you can tokenize the input with [`tokenize`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html) and parse it with something like [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import tokenize
import ast

values = []

with open('input_file') as f:
    for token_type, token_string, _, _, _ in tokenize.generate_tokens(f.readline):
        # Ignore newlines and the file-ending dummy token.
        if token_type in (tokenize.ENDMARKER, tokenize.NEWLINE, tokenize.NL):
            continue
        values.append(ast.literal_eval(token_string))
```

Comment: the only thing here, is I am having trouble with empty lines, in the file, it seems that they break things, I am sure it is easy to fix

Comment: @MarkGaleck: Looks like there are two types of newline tokens, and I was only skipping one. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_val`

```
>>> import ast

>>> ast.literal_eval('2')
2
>>> type(ast.literal_eval('2')
<type 'int'>

>>> ast.literal_eval('[1,2,3]')
[1, 2, 3]
>>> type(ast.literal_eval('[1,2,3]')
<type 'list'>

>>> ast.literal_eval('"a"')
'a'
>>> type(ast.literal_eval('"a"')
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: Not until you've broken it up though.

Comment: well yes, but I have to insert commas into the file, which are part of Python syntax.  I don't want anything except unquoted spaces

Comment: You cannot just read an entire file in and `literal_eval` the whole thing, you'll have to do some semblance of parsing first.

Answer (score 0):

This almost gets you there, but due to the way strings work, it ends up combining the two strings:

```
import ast

with open('tokens.txt') as in_file:
    current_string = ''
    tokens = []
    for line in in_file:
        current_string += line.strip()
        try:
            new_token = ast.literal_eval(current_string)
            tokens.append(new_token)
            current_string = ''
        except SyntaxError:
            print("Couldn't parse current line, combining with next")

tokens
Out[8]: [2, '\\nfoobarfoo bar', None]
```

The problem is that in Python, if you have two string literals sitting next to each other, they concatenate even if you don't use `+`, e.g.:

```
x = 'string1' 'string2'
x
Out[10]: 'string1string2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for posting an answer to my own question, but it looks like, what works, is that I replace unquoted whitespace (including newlines), with commas, and then put [] around the whole thing and import.

Comment: You're going to have problems figuring out which whitespace is unquoted.

Comment: If that works, it might be worth posting code so anyone in future with a similar problem can use it. It's OK to answer your own questions.

Comment: There is no problem posting (and accepting) the correct answer to your own question (although you wont get points for accepting it).  But this answer doesn't seem to solve your problem, which is that you must write a parser that observes Python's (somewhat complex) quoting system in order to figure out which white space to transform.

Comment: yes I realize to figure out which whitespace is unquoted, is not trivial